# When I upgrade MatlabRuntime from 2019b to 2021b,I hava a proplem

Tags: java, matlab, matlab-deployment

When I upgrade MatlabRuntime from 2019b to 2021b and I hava a springboot service used matlab, I have a problem,I import newest javabulider.jar(2021b) into my springboot service, then I package and publish my service into server,then report an error,can someone help me,thank you

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Failed to find the required library libmwmclmcrrt.so.9.7 on java.library.path.
This library is typically installed along with MATLAB or the MATLAB Runtime. Its absence may indicate an issue with that installation or 
the current path configuration, or a mismatch with the architecture of the Java interpreter on the path.
MATLAB Runtime version this component is attempting to use: 9.7.
Java interpreter architecture: glnxa64.
```

I need someone can help me

Comment: The error mentions a possible point of trouble: version numbers. What are your versions?

Comment: `Its absence may indicate an issue with that installation` - this might be something you need to raise with MathWorks support

Comment: my mrc version is 2021b

Answer (score 1):

The message:

Failed to find the required library libmwmclmcrrt.so.9.7

Indicates that the application you are trying to execute was compiled with Matlab 2019b and that the corresponding MCR is not installed.